# Take a string and an array and return a modified merged array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have to build a method that takes an array and a string. The method should return an array with three elements. Its element at index 0 should be the string argument, and it should not include the last element of the array argument.

For array:

```
best_teams = ([Boston Celtics, LA Lakers, Chicago Bulls]
```

and string:

```
my_team = ("Utah Jazz")
```

I expect the output:

```
[Utah Jazz, Boston Celtics, LA Lakers]
```

I tried this:

```
def teams(best_teams, my_team)
  sec = my_team.split + best_teams
  return sec - sec[3].split
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a school assignment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Without giving too much away, I recommend searching the ruby docs for the correct method for doing this action. To give a hint, you want to look for a keyword similar to "prepend" because you want to prepend the array with a string. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

Comment: Have you tried anything _at all_?

Comment: I tried turning the string into an array with .split, then merging the two arrays with the (+) operator and later subtracting the last element of the second array with the (-). Doesn't seem to work though

Comment: Show the code that isn't working

Comment: If you tried something that's great, but it's important to show the code. Edit your question to include that attempt.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code in the question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the array methods `unshift`, and `pop`

Comment: There is a problem with your array `best_teams`. It should be `['Toronto Raptors', 'Boston Celtics', 'Houston Rockets', 'Golden State Warriors']`.

Comment: Remember that in Ruby the `return` statement is usually omitted if that's the last line as that's implicit.

Comment: aconsuegra's code did the job. Anyone could help explain what was wrong with my code (find it in the question)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DoctorRue it seems like you're a bit confused about what `split` does. You should use the Ruby console `irb` and try out a few experiments. For example `"Utah Jazz".split` - this will give you an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Look,  asuming the following values:

```
best_teams = ['Boston Celtics', 'LA Lakers', 'Chicago Bulls']
my_team = "Utah Jazz"

def teams(best_teams, my_team)
  # sec = nil
  sec = my_team.split + best_teams
  # the values at this point are
  # sec = ["Utah", "Jazz"] + ['Boston Celtics', 'LA Lakers', 'Chicago Bulls']
  # your single team name now become in an array with two values 
  # finally
  # sec = ["Utah", "Jazz", 'Boston Celtics', 'LA Lakers', 'Chicago Bulls']
  return sec - sec[3].split
  # ["Utah", "Jazz", 'Boston Celtics', 'LA Lakers', 'Chicago Bulls'] - ["LA", "Lakers"]
  # ["Utah", "Jazz", "Boston Celtics", "LA Lakers", "Chicago Bulls"]
end
```

Please check
https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split.
The real problem is that  I guess so you don't know how split work